# Trigger problem mouseover/mouseleave javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make an effect when the user switches elements on hover but I have an issue.

Here is my code

```js
var oStudyRows = document.querySelectorAll('.study_row');

oStudyRows.forEach(function(oStudyRow) {
  oStudyRow.addEventListener('mouseover', function(e) {
    console.log('enter')
    oStudyRow.classList.add('blub');
  })
  oStudyRow.addEventListener('mouseleave', function(e) {
    oStudyRow.classList.remove('blub');
    console.log('out');
  })
})
```

```html
<div class="wrapper_study">
  <div class="study_row study">
    <div class="study_year">aaaa</div>
    <div class="study_name">bbbb</div>
  </div>
  <div class="study_row work">
    <div class="study_year">aaaa</div>
    <div class="study_name">bbbbb</div>
  </div>
  <div class="study_row work">
    <div class="study_year">aaaa</div>
    <div class="study_name">bbbbbb</div>
  </div>
  <div class="study_row study">
    <div class="study_year">aaaa</div>
    <div class="study_name">bbbbb</div>
  </div>
  <div class="study_row work">
    <div class="study_year">aaaaa</div>
    <div class="study_name">bbbb</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

When I "enter" in the first row and I "leave" to the top , the enter/out work correctly, I have "enter/out" in the console but when I hover row1 to row2 I have a mutiple console log.

[screenshot console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DImwx.png)

Someone can help me and explain to me why it doesn't work properly, please?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

The children divs contained in `.study_row` will bubble the event to the parent. So to make only the parent fire the event, I set pointer-events to none for any children of `.study_row`.

There are better alternatives on setting the event handler here, but this is the solution taking the less modification to your strategy.

```js
var oStudyRows = document.querySelectorAll('.study_row');

oStudyRows.forEach(function(oStudyRow){
    oStudyRow.addEventListener('mouseover', function(e){
        console.log('enter')
        oStudyRow.classList.add('blub');
    })
    oStudyRow.addEventListener('mouseleave', function(e){
        oStudyRow.classList.remove('blub');
        console.log('out');
    })
})
```

```css
.study_row{
  border: solid 1px red;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}

.study_row *{
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper_study">
   <div class="study_row study">
      <div class="study_year">aaaa</div>
      <div class="study_name">bbbb</div>
   </div>  
   <div class="study_row work">
      <div class="study_year">aaaa</div> 
      <div class="study_name">bbbbb</div>
   </div>  
   <div class="study_row work">
      <div class="study_year">aaaa</div> 
      <div class="study_name">bbbbbb</div>
   </div>  
   <div class="study_row study">
      <div class="study_year">aaaa</div>
      <div class="study_name">bbbbb</div>
   </div>  
   <div class="study_row work">
      <div class="study_year">aaaaa</div> 
      <div class="study_name">bbbb</div>
   </div>   
</div>
```

Here's a strategy using one single function to handle both the `mouseover` and `mouseout` events firing just on the `.wrapper_study` container element (and all of its children through bubbling .. excepts for elements that got `pointer-events:none` due to the rule `.study_row *`). To pursue this strategy I had to replace `mouseleave` with `mouseout` because the former one doesn't support bubbling.

You can find more on those topic here:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mouseleave_event
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mouseout_event
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#event_bubbling_and_capture

```js
//one single event handler
function generalHandler(event){
  //element firing the event
  const eventTarget = event.target;
  //if eventTarget is a .study_row
  if(eventTarget.classList.contains('study_row')) {   
    //if event is mouseover
    if (event.type == 'mouseover'){
      eventTarget.classList.add('blub');
      //console.log('--enter');    
    }
    //if event is mouseout
    else if(event.type == 'mouseout'){
      eventTarget.classList.remove('blub');
      //console.log('--out');
    }      
  }
}

const mainContainer = document.querySelector('.wrapper_study');
mainContainer.addEventListener('mouseover', generalHandler);
mainContainer.addEventListener('mouseout', generalHandler);
```

```css
.study_row{
  border: solid 1px red;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.study_row *{
  pointer-events: none;
}

.blub{
  border-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper_study">
  <div class="study_row study">
    <div class="study_year">aaaa</div>
    <div class="study_name">bbbb</div>
  </div>
  <div class="study_row work">
    <div class="study_year">aaaa</div>
    <div class="study_name">bbbbb</div>
  </div>
  <div class="study_row work">
    <div class="study_year">aaaa</div>
    <div class="study_name">bbbbbb</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank for your answer and your solution !
Could you explain me the better alternative please ?

Comment: I added a second strategy using a single function to handle both the events and attaching it as event handler only on one element (the main container)